# Git ignore files after renaming in the VisualStudio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, rename, gitignore

I have `Visual Studio` solution. I renamed 1 file in the solution:
It was `CartCreated` and now it is `BinTypeCreated`. After renaming `Visual Studio` highlights this file as ignored:
[image]

`Git` shows that file `CartCreated` was removed, but doesn't show that file `BinTypeCreated` was added (as it does usually):

> Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add/rm ..." to update
>   what will be committed)   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard
>   changes in working directory)
>
> ```
>     deleted:    Src/xxx.M2/Bin/CartCreated.cs
>     modified:   src/xxx.M2/xxx.M2.csproj
> ```

According to  `.gitignore` - file shouldn't be ignored. I tried to give different name to that file - it doesn't help. I tried to search the answer - but usually the answer is -  *check .gitignore*.

- How to force git to track renamed file?
- Why VisualStudio added red    point near to file name?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem related to the fact that folder name is "Bin" - which is standart git ignore thing.

- To force git to track renamed file, we need to exlcude the target
  file from .gitignore. To solve the problem is just added exception to
  .gitignore, so now it looks like:

> ...
>   [Bb]in
>   ...
>   !Src/xxx/Bin
>   ...

- `Visual Studio 2015` marked the file as 'ignored' just because it can
  read git settings and in a some way cooperates with `Git` (also it can
  create empty repository etc.)

Comment: A couple things:  First, excluding `Bin/` is not a git standard. It is a VisualStudio standard (regardless of which VCS is used).  The other thing is, you may want to think about whether including the `bin/` directory is the right solution.  It is *if* `Bin/` is a source folder... which I think it might be here, but that's contrary to convention with VisualStudio so you might want to revisit it. If build products are placed in `Bin/` then you still probably want those excluded, so you'd want a more specific rule (`!Bin/*.cs` maybe) or to force-add specific files and not use an exception rule

Comment: Thanks. Good point  about "git ignore standart", i agree that it is not a git standart, but GitExtensions provides ignoring patterns, so i think it is "GitExtensions" standart too.